# Is there an std view for random access iterators, as std::span is for contiguous iterators?

Tags: c++

Is there a standard view for random access iterators, as std::span is for contiguous iterators?

It is a piece of cake to implement such thing, but I ask before reinvent the wheel. I don't see something like that on cppreference.

Comment: Range-v3 has `any_view`.

Comment: A random access iterator is also a forward iterator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::span` is a pointer and a size (or equivalently two pointers). It doesn't need to do type erasure.

A `random_access_view` would have the overhead of type erasure, so I don't expect one to be standardised.

Instead I would suggest a template constrained to [`std::ranges::random_access_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/random_access_range), possibly in conjunction with [`std::ranges::viewable_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/viewable_range) if you need a view specifically.